# shortcut to replace all strings in previous bash command

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

`man bash` describes a very useful [Event Designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators)

> ^string1^string2^
>
> Quick substitution. Repeat the last command, replacing string1 with string2. Equivalent to ''!!:s/string1/string2/''

Is there a way  to execute `!!:gs/string1/string2/` when typing in `@string1@string2@` on the command line to replace all occurrences in the previous command? (`@` or any other designated character/string)

Comment: curious to why you would like to do this? It's not like a `^` is difficult to type...

Comment: @FredrikPihl `^from^to^` only substitutes the _first_ occurrence, I'm looking for a shortcut to substitute _all_ occurrences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^string1^string2^:g&`

See question [Replace all occurrences of a word in the last command](https://superuser.com/a/940539/205301).

See [Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) in [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction).

Answer (score 1):

#### Shortly: no!

In fact, there may exist a way, using `trap "..." debug'...

Something like:

```
trap 'if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ ^@(.*)@(.*)@$ ]] ;then
     BASH_LAST=${BASH_LAST//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}};
     $BASH_LAST;
     unset BASH_COMMAND;
   else BASH_LAST=$BASH_COMMAND;
   fi;
 ' debug
```

This is quick and dirty, there left an execution error, but I think: It may be a way to do it.

***Edit 01***

This is a little better, but history stay quite wrong:

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap '
    if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ ^@(.*)@(.*)@$ ]] ;then
        BASH_LAST="${BASH_LAST//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}"
        $BASH_LAST
        false
      else
        BASH_LAST="$BASH_COMMAND"
      fi' debug
```

***But warn:*** I do this for *fun*, for playing with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and to understand how it work... This is not intended to be used in *effective* final solution!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your code example? I got it to execute by using `bash -c "$BASH_LAST"`, but it insists on printing `@foo@bar@: command not found` after the output of the modified command.

Comment: @Alex Edited... This work *better*, but there left a lot of this to work around... Feel free to edit my answer to add some explanation if you find it useful ;-)