# Replace string from previous command and execute

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'd like to know the shortest command for correcting a mistake in the previously executed command.

Given I executed the following command

```
cd /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

I would like to be able to execute a new command that takes the previous command, pipes it through `grep` or a similar Unix tool, and then executes. Something like this in (my admittedly uneducated) psuedo-command.

```sh
!! | xargs 's/$1/USERNAME/cirrostratus/g'
```

This command would execute

```sh
cd /Users/cirrostratus/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

Alternately, piping a string, searching and replacing on it and executing in one line would be my second choice.

Comment: Choose `USER_NAME` or `USERNAME` but be consistent.  `grep` is for finding text; `sed` is for changing text; `awk` can be used for changing text but is arguably overkill for the scenario.  Would you expect the `cd /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Preferences/ByHost` command to succeed?  `cd` is a built-in command which complicates things in some respects.  Why don't you just `cd ~cirrostratus/Library/Preferences/ByHost`?  Does: `cd $(echo $_ | sed 's/USERNAME/cirrostratus/')` do the job for you?

Comment: In a script, or on the command line?

Comment: @tripleee in the command line por favor.

Comment: Jonathan, using `cd` was just a meaningless example—I know it's built in, it's the first command I learned as a kid. I execute commands in zsh or bash thousands of times each week and a micro-optimization of quickly correcting mistakes I just made in a previous command would help me over time, and just feel cleaner IMO than moving my cursor over to correct the mistake. `cd $(echo $_ | sed 's/USERNAME/cirrostratus/')` doesn't work in this case because my goal is to correct mistakes (typos, bad copy paste etc.). Thx for the info re: grep not replacing text.

Comment: You could take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16284715/1765658

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanna replace a **all occurences** of a string (switch `g`) you'll need to write:

```
!!:gs/oldstring/newstring/
```

This will replace *oldstring* by *newstring* in you're last command **and** run them **and** store the result to history.

Otherwise: then syntaxe `^oldstring^newstring^`  is a shortcut for:

```
!!:s/oldstring/newstring/
```

replacing only first found occurence of string.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to skip having to press enter twice (i.e. once to perform the replacement and once again to execute the modified command)?

Comment: Yes surely, but based on `trap debug`... Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16284715/1765658